# How to avoid implicit dependencies between Service class and Model class in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, dependencies

If I have a site design which follows a dependency flow of:

Handler Class <-> Service Class <-> Mapper Class <-> Model Class

Handler receives the request, Service contains the logic, Mapper performs the DB queries and uses the Model to work on the data, while the Model represents a single record in the DB.

Ideally, you would have explicitly defined dependencies on/from the neighboring layers. So if I change a particular layer, only the two immediately neighboring layers *might* be affected.

However, I realized I may be using some bad practices. In particular, I have the Service class call a method on the Mapper class. The Mapper class would return an instance of the Model class.  But if I then call a method of the Model class, from within the Service class, there is now a direct and implicit dependency between the Service class and the Model class.

I have a few thoughts on how to address this, which I'll outline below. But I feel there has got to be a better way. So I'm curious what the general consensus is on avoid these implicit dependency situations while avoiding unnecessary processing.

1. Inject an empty instance of the Model into the Service class to make the dependency explicit. But this seems clunky and doesn't account for multi-record result sets.
2. Specify the Model interface as the return type in the Mapper Interface for that method. To me, this seems like the preferred method. However, it gets complicated when you have to return multi-record result sets. I would rather not unnecessarily iterate through the entire result set within the Mapper class, before I even begin to use the results for the actual application logic. At a minimum, that would be O(2n) time complexity for nearly every query. So I've just been returning an object which is an \Iterable and iterating over that within the Service class (so O(n) is the floor instead of O(2n)). But this is the same situation where there is an implicit dependency on the Model class.

I've been trying to find out if it's possible to specify the type of object the \Iterable will iterate over, like you can with arrays (IE: `int[]` is an array of integers). The best I could come up with was to create a custom Iterator class specific to the Model class. Is this the preferred method of eliminating these implicit dependencies, while avoiding unnecessary loops?

Much appreciation!

**Edit based on feedback:**

I don't have any code which fails, and this question isn't meant to be specific to any real code. This question is solely about an abstract problem. That is why no code was originally included. But based on feedback I've drafted up the following to help make the purposed situation more clear.

Just ignore the Handler class, it's not needed to illustrate the concept, I was just trying to describe the overall structure with it to make it easier to identify the design pattern.

The Service class:

```
namespace App\Service;

class Service implements ServiceInterface 
{
    protected mapperInterface $mapper;

    public function __construct(mapperInterface $mapper){
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
    }

    public getAllRows() {
       $iterator = $this->mapper->getAllRows();
       while($iterator->valid()){
           $current = $iterator->current();
           // This line creates an implicit dependency on the Model class
           $name = $current->getName();
           $iterator->next();
       }
    }
}
```

The Mapper Class:
namespace App\Mapper;

```
class Mapper implements MapperInterface 
{
    protected modelInterface $modelPrototype;

    public function __construct(modelInterface $model){
        $this->modelPrototype = $model;
    }

    public getAllRows() : Iterator {
       // Execute SQL then hydrate into an iterator over multiple "Model" objects into a variable ($resultSet in this case)

       return $resultSet; // This is an Iterator instance of which each iteration contains a "Model" object.
    }
}
```

The Model class:

```
class Model implements ModelInterface 
{
    protected string $name;

    public function getName() : string {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name) : void {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

It is specifically this line in the Service class which creates an implicit dependency between the Service class and the Model class (bypassing the transitive dependency through the Mapper class):

```
$name = $current->getName();
```

There are two ways to correct this, either make the dependency explicit, or eliminate the dependency in the first place. I've listed my ideas on *how* to achieve those two options. But I am curious what the most common solution to this situation is. Is there some other option or method of addressing this which I have not thought of? Or is one of my proposed ideas the generally preferred method.

Comment: Can you please post some examples of what you've tried and explain where it fails? It's harder for us to follow along when it's just a wall of text, explaining abstract concepts.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I've drafted up some pseudo code to better illustrate the situation I'm speaking of. But it's just pseudo code as my question is solely about an abstract situation. There is no "real" code at the moment. Hope it helps, and thank you for the comment.

Comment: `$name = $current->getName();` - That would be more of a dependency on the model interface though? Not sure how you would avoid that if you do need to call some method on the instance?

Comment: I see no issue;. Your service class (sometimes referred to as a controller class) is what normally implements a requirements use case and I can't imagine how it would do so without directly interacting with your model class instances (e.g. domain objects ). That these objects are stored on a database are the reason for the mapper objects, i.e. just to handle the retrieval and storage of these model objects. If tomorrow they are stored differently, then your mapper class implementation will change but ideally not your business logic as implemented in the model and service classes.

Comment: I mostly agree, the Service class needs to know something about the data it's working with. And it's certainly possible I'm taking this design pattern to an extreme. But with the way the examples are configured, if the model class is changed so the methods are renamed to `setFirstName()` and `getFirstName()`, the Service class would have to be changed accordingly. But when I look up what is dependent on the Model class, the Service class will not be found, only the Mapper class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically i also don't see a dependency. The `Service` ask it's neighbour `Mapper` for a collection of `Model` and it provides one. The `Mapper` uses the `Model` and hydrates the data from whereever. So communication-wise everything is fine.

If you would access data in your `Service` with

```
$this->mapper->model->someModelMethod();
```

instead of

```
$this->mapper->getAllRows();
```

only then you would violate something at least in the sense of the law of demeter.

The dependency on the level you might think having an issue is probably some kind of tight coupling inside your layers, which is generally okay for this use case.

If you wanna decouple it between layers/modules/units consider introducing another kind of data container to pass around.

For example using some kind of `Transfer Object` and map/hydrate the data from your model to it. This transfer object can be used to pass around e.g. on the communication layer like Controllers, Services etc. You only rely on the transfer objects properties but not on the model itself. Only your mapper has to be adapted if something changed on both the `Model` and the `Transfer Object`

Comment: Thank you for the response @JimPanse. Okay, so you're saying the issue with the provided example is that the Mapper (and it's interface) simply returns an `\Iterator` object which could be a collection of anything. The key is to make the Mapper (and it's interface) return an iterator specific to the model, such as `modelIteratorInterface()`.  This way the Service class expects that specific iterator which is tied to the model, since that is what is specified in the Mapper interface. As a result it then becomes an explicit dependency, making the impact of changes to the Model easy to identify.

Comment: I'm going to give this post a bit more time, but this seems like the correct solution. I'll mark as accepted in 2 days (so you get the bounty) if there aren't any other answers.

Comment: Also, you're saying the creation of `modelIteratorInterface()` probably isn't necessary, it's just an extra step I could take if I really wanted to decouple the classes further. So I'm probably taking this design pattern a bit to the extreme.  It's really only important to avoid code such as `$this->mapper->model->someModelMethod();` where something like `$model = $this->mapper->getAllRows();` then `$model->someModelMethod();` is okay?

Comment: My core statement is, that tight coupling inside self-contained units like modules layers etc. shouldn't be anything you have to excessive fight against since coupling is unavoidale to make things work together. What you can do is to find the borders of your software areals and create contracts how to communicate between these units.

Comment: `$model = $this->mapper->getAllRows();` wouldn't return you the model since the mapper takes the model and make something out of it. That you just pass exactly what the model provides 1:1 to your Service is a detail, but is in the responsibility of the mapper at this point. If your application design expects a model/entity or whatever "lower level detail", it's still okay to get this passed to the Service

Comment: Okay, so it isn't breaking the pattern, it's simply a design choice at that point. Thank you for clarifying.